# In Quarkus how to direct ALL logging to file based logging when run as a service?

Tags: quarkus

We have several Quarkus apps each configured with console & file based logging.  What we have found is certain errors that happen in Quarkus don't make it to either the console & files and some do make it to the console but not the file.  Obviously the console is only visible when starting the app from the console which is rare, we normally start the app as a Linux service.

How can we configure out Quarkus logging so ALL logging goes to the file?

Here is an example of how we have logging configured currently:

`log: level: INFO handler: console: "CONSOLE": async: false enable: true format: '%K{level}%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p (%t) [%c.%M()] %s%e%n' file: "FILE": async: false enable: true format: '%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p (%t) [%c.%M()] %s%e%n' #level: INFO path: '/opt/remote-server/logs/remote-server.log' rotation: file-suffix: .yyyy-MM-dd max-backup-index: 999 max-file-size: 40000000 rotate-on-boot: true "AUDIT": async: false enable: true format: '%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p (%t) [%c.%M()] %s%e%n' #level: INFO path: '/opt/remote-server/logs/remote-server-audit.log' rotation: file-suffix: .yyyy-MM-dd max-backup-index: 999 max-file-size: 40000000 rotate-on-boot: true "DATAAUDIT": async: false enable: true format: '%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p (%t) [%c.%M()] %s%e%n' #level: INFO path: '/opt/remote-server/logs/remote-server-dataaudit.log' rotation: file-suffix: .yyyy-MM-dd max-backup-index: 999 max-file-size: 40000000 rotate-on-boot: true category: "com.bs.util.accumulator.AccumulatorLogger": level: INFO use-parent-handlers: false handlers: DATAAUDIT "com.bs.audit.Auditor": level: INFO handlers: AUDIT "org.hibernate.sql": level: ERROR handlers: FILE "org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql": level: ERROR handlers: FILE "io.quarkus.http.access-log": level: ERROR handlers: FILE "com.bs.sdl.async": level: ERROR handlers: FILE "com.bs.sdl.service": level: ERROR handlers: FILE "com.bs": level: INFO handlers: FILE`

Here is an example of an error that does not make it to the file but does make it to the console if started from the console.

`2023-07-14 20:34:52,659 ERROR [io.qua.ver.htt.run.QuarkusErrorHandler] (executor-thread-2) HTTP Request to /datasync/orchestration/remote failed, error id: bbe963ab-803c-4af1-a1b8-52beccf3287e-1: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: com.bs.aws.exception.client.KmsClientCreateException: Unable to create an KmsClient after employing the following strategies, [EC2InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider] at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:368) at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:218) at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:519) at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:261) at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:161) at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364) at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:164) at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:247) at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.RequestDispatcher.service(RequestDispatcher.java:82) at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.dispatch(VertxRequestHandler.java:147) at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler$1.run(VertxRequestHandler.java:93) at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:576) at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449) at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1452) at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29) at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29) at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) Caused by: com.bs.aws.exception.client.KmsClientCreateException: Unable to create an KmsClient after employing the following strategies, [EC2InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider] at com.bs.aws.factory.EC2InstanceProfileCredentialsProviderStrategyAwsClientFactory.getAwsKmsClient(EC2InstanceProfileCredentialsProviderStrategyAwsClientFactory.java:234) at com.bs.aws.api.impl.AwsKmsApi.<init>(AwsKmsApi.java:92) at com.bs.aws.api.impl.AwsKmsApi.<init>(AwsKmsApi.java:83) at com.bs.aws.api.impl.AwsKmsApi_Bean.create(Unknown Source) at com.bs.aws.api.impl.AwsKmsApi_Bean.create(Unknown Source) at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.createInstanceHandle(AbstractSharedContext.java:113) at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext$1.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:37) at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext$1.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:34) at io.quarkus.arc.impl.LazyValue.get(LazyValue.java:26) at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ComputingCache.computeIfAbsent(ComputingCache.java:69) at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:34) at com.bs.aws.api.impl.AwsKmsApi_Bean.get(Unknown Source) at com.bs.aws.api.impl.AwsKmsApi_Bean.get(Unknown Source) at com.bs.remote.server.rest.EnterpriseDataSyncOrchestrationREST_Bean.create(Unknown Source) at com.bs.remote.server.rest.EnterpriseDataSyncOrchestrationREST_Bean.create(Unknown Source) at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.createInstanceHandle(AbstractSharedContext.java:113) at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext$1.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:37) at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext$1.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:34) at io.quarkus.arc.impl.LazyValue.get(LazyValue.java:26) at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ComputingCache.computeIfAbsent(ComputingCache.java:69) at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:34) at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ClientProxies.getApplicationScopedDelegate(ClientProxies.java:21) at com.bs.remote.server.rest.EnterpriseDataSyncOrchestrationREST_ClientProxy.arc$delegate(Unknown Source) at com.bs.remote.server.rest.EnterpriseDataSyncOrchestrationREST_ClientProxy.arc_contextualInstance(Unknown Source) at io.quarkus.arc.ClientProxy.unwrap(ClientProxy.java:52) at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.ClientProxyUnwrapper.apply(ClientProxyUnwrapper.java:15) at io.quarkus.resteasy.common.runtime.QuarkusInjectorFactory$UnwrappingPropertyInjector.inject(QuarkusInjectorFactory.java:74) at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.resourcefactory.POJOResourceFactory.createResource(POJOResourceFactory.java:80) at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:401) at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:69) at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:492) ... 15 more`

This error happens well after the Quarkus app has started. We have had other errors at startup that don't even go to the console.

How can I configure Quarkus so ALL errors/logging goes to both the console & logging regardless of how the app is started console/service?

Tried to get all logging to go to the configured log file but it seems that certain Quarkus errors do not go to the log file.